# Why is it beneficial to ditch 'this' in this example

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to grasp the concepts of Javascript through online video courses, where I came upon this example below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oi0NY8Pen8

The instructor used this example first

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
    this.loc++;
  };
  return obj;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
amy.move();
```

and then changed the carlike function to

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
    obj.loc++;
  };
  return obj;
};
```

Saying the `Instead of referring to the parameter this which gets bound to a new value each time move is invoked we can use obj`

How is `this` getting bound to  new value. How can using obj prevent this.

Comment: What is the change? Both the codes look the same to me

Comment: The value of `this` in any `function` is determined when and by how it's called, not by how it's defined. [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski—mod [*bind*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `amy.move()`, within `move` the "variable" `this` gets the value of `amy`, which is an object.  If `move` contains the code `this.loc++`, then the value of the property `amy.loc` will be incremented.

You can, however, invoke that function in other ways.  For example:

```
var func = amy.move; // copies reference to function into variable func
func();              // "this" is unspecified
```

In the above case, because `this` is unspecified, it defaults to `window` (in non-strict mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Or:

```
var bill = { loc: 4 };
amy.move.call(bill); // "this" is bill, not amy
```

On the other hand, if the `move` function contains the code `obj.loc++`, then it will always increment the `loc` of same object: namely, the one that was passed to `carlike` when this instance of `move` was created:

```
var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var bill = { loc: 4 };
amy.move.call(bill); // "this" is bill, not amy
console.log(amy.loc); // prints 2
console.log(bill.loc); // prints 4
```

The `move` function, when created, becomes a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on the local variable `obj` within `carlike`.

In this small example, there is no particular benefit to doing this, but closures are a powerful technique in general.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the *move* function as:

```
amy.move();
```

then you are setting the value of *this* within *move* to *amy*. If you do:

```
var b = amy.move;
b();
```

you are now calling the function without setting *this*, so it defaults to the global/window object in non–strict mode, and is undefined in strict mode. By using:

```
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
    obj.loc++;
  };
```

then the function keeps a reference to *obj* via a closure, so no matter how the function is called, *obj* always references the object originally passed to *carlike*.

Answer (score 1):

Since `this` in javascript is decided at function invocation. Using it inside methods causes unwanted bugs. You may not realize this if you call the function yourself using `amy.move()`.

Ex:

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.loc++;
  };
  return obj;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
amy.move(); => this will corresponds to object which are returned from constructor.

setTimeout(amy.move, 1000) => this will corresponds to window
```

Since the constructor is returning the object, its safe to use obj inside the function `amy`.

Ref: [this in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: "*…causes unwanted bugs*" you mean there can be wanted bugs? ;-)

Comment: If you know how to use bind/fat arrows then its fine, else you will surely end up with a nasty bug!